# Can any one help me to convert sql query to Magento Customer model form?

Tags: mysql, magento-1.7

I am using query below.

```
INSERT INTO customer_entity_int set  value_id='', attribute_id='134',entity_id='".$entity_id."',value='1',entity_type_id='1'
```

but I need to convert it into ***Magento*** form. ie sql injection free query.

Comment: Add an example of your effort

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do so:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
    ->load($entity_id)
    ->setData([attribute_code], '1')
    ->save();
```

Note: the attribute code is not the integer ID, but rather the text value (attribute_code in the eav_attribute table).